# "Factorisation" in special linear groups over rings of integers

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algorithms

It is known that for any number field $F$ with infinitely many units (i.e. $F$ is not $\mathbb Q$ or an imaginary quadratic field) with ring of integers $O$ the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}_2(O)$ is generated by the "elementary matrices" :
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1& a\\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, \, \begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ a&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for $a \in O$. See for example [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105857/generators-for-sl-2r-for-rings-of-integers-r).

The proof of this fact that I skimmed (in Bernhard Liehl's Crelle paper, [MR0611449](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=611449)) did not seem to me to translate to a clear algorithm allowing to compute a decomposition of a given matrix into a product of elementary matrices. Is such an algorithm known?

Comment: The discussion in Witte-Morris' article http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/2007/13-17.html seems to suggest that they generate a finite index subgroup with an explicit bound, but possibly not always the whole group? Possibly the proof is effective, anyway (and it gives a decomposition into a bounded number of matrices).

Comment: I think that in the case of 2 by 2 matrices they generate the entire group (this is what's proved in the paper I linked, also I think it should follow from the congruence subgroup property in this case).

Comment: Note that over the $\mathbb{Z}$, the elementary matrices do generate $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Your condition on $F$ implies that elementary matrices with coefficients in an ideal of $O$ generate a subgroup of finite index in $SL_2(O)$